# Квадратные или круглые скобки?

Tags: оформление-текста

Текст из Корана: «Когда небо расколется, когда
звезды осыплются, когда моря
смешаются, когда могилы перевернутся, *(тогда)* каждая душа
узнает, что она совершила и *(что
оставила)* после себя» (82:1–5).
Слова в скобках курсивом отсутствуют в оригинальном арабском тексте, они вставлены в русский перевод для большей понятности.
Допустимо ли их писать в скобках курсивом (т. е. выделяя шрифтом) или правильнее в квадратных скобках тем же шрифтом?
Не могу найти чёткого правила...
В реальных переводах пишут и так и так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Единственное правило, которое мне пришло на ум, — это правило о вставке в цитату слов цитирующего:

> Если цитирующий вставляет в цитату свой поясняющий текст или
> раскрывает сокращенное слово, то это пояснение заключается в
> квадратные или угловые скобки: **«Спасибо за любование Муром [сыном М.
> Цветаевой]…» – пишет М. Цветаева Б. Пастернаку в 1927 г...**

Но у вас не совсем тот случай. Для сравнения: в Синодальном переводе Библии слова́, вставленные *для ясности и связи речи*, по всему тексту набраны просто курсивом. Я думаю, такой подход допустим и в вашем случае, главное — соблюдать единообразие по всему тексту и указать в начале или в конце, что, мол, *курсивом* или *квадратными скобками* (в зависимости от того, какой вариант выберете) *отмечены слова́, отсутствующие в оригинале и добавленные в перевод для ясности и связи речи*.

Comment: В некоторых полных переводах Корана так и сделано, но в данном случае это цитаты из Корана в большом тексте (газете), где присутствуют слова курсивом по другой причине (правда в других статьях газеты), то есть не получается единообразия по всей газете.

Comment: В таком случае, на мой взгляд, лучше сделать какое-либо уникальное выделение, которое в газете больше не используется, кроме как в цитатах из Корана. С другой стороны, если цитируется какой-либо конкретный перевод смыслов, например Кулиева, то, возможно, стОит соблюдать именно тот вариант выделения, который использовал переводчик. Это будет по правилам цитирования.

Comment: Пожалуй Вы правы (свалим всё на переводчика). Спасибо!